# tooltip not coming at correct position in firefox in chartlist.js

Tags: jquery, css, charts, position, tooltip

I am using [chatlist.js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) to show charts and using its one of the method to show tooltip on chart.

Tooltip on chart is coming fine on all other browsers except **firefox** I cant find any solution over google and there is no support page on chartlist website.

I am using following default code for tooltip x and y positions

```
$toolTip.css({
      left: (event.originalEvent.layerX || event.offsetX) - $toolTip.width() / 2 - 10,
      top: (event.originalEvent.layerY || event.offsetY) - $toolTip.height() - 40
    });
```

[image]

Comment: *"there is no support page"* - you could open an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues)

Comment: okay cool @mpf82 but still I can ask here as well no??

Comment: Sure you can, I just wanted to point out an alternative in case you don't get an answer here ;)

Comment: By the way, I just stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/442), looks similar to the problem you're having.

Comment: I might be way off, but since the js is using top/left attributes, does the parent/class has a position relative/absolute?

Comment: @mpf82 hahahah :) I saw this link before and I did not try it because code does not have any change except he has done a | b to b | a. I dont know how but it worked :p thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem; put **position: relative** in your chart wrapper div.